# Json can not deserialize instance Error in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, http

I am trying to send a json long list and take records from db.

My controller is:

```
@Api(tags = Endpoint.RESOURCE_customer, description = "customer Resource")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public class CustomerResourceController {

    private final customerService customerService;


    public CustomerResourceController(customerService customerService) {

        this.customerService = customerService;
    }

    @ApiOperation(
            value = "Return customer",
            response = customerDto.class, responseContainer="List"
    )
    @PostMapping(value = Endpoint.RRESOURCE_customer_ID)
    public List<customerDto> getCustomersByIds(@RequestBody List<Long> ids) {
        return customerService.findcustomerIds(ids);
    }

}
```

and client class is:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: " + MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public interface CustomerClient {

@RequestLine("POST /customer/customers/search")
    List<LocGrpDto> getCustomersByIds(@RequestBody @Validated List<Long> ids);
}
```

And i test this service in postman with JSON:

> {     "ids": [1,7,8] }

But I get this error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-10-05T13:29:57.645+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3cb8b584; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3cb8b584; line: 1, column: 1]",
    "path": "/api/v1/customer/customers/search",
    "errors": []
}
```

What is the problem? Do you see any problem here or it may be caused because of my service class or dto classes ?

Comment: If you look at `@RequestBody List<Long> ids` then you can tell that it takes a list (JSON equivalent _JSONArray_). You can change it to Map if you want to stick to `{ "ids": [1,7,8] }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try requesting with the payload `[1,7,8]`, not `{"ids": [1,7,8]}`.

Your JSON would translate to a request body with the next format.

```
class Body {

    private List<Long> ids;

    // constructor, getters and setters 

}
```

For a REST client, you can take a look at `RestTemplate`.

```
RestTemplate template;
List<Long> ids;
List<CustomerDto> = template.exchange(
            "/customer/customers/search",
            HttpMethod.POST,
            new HttpEntity<>(ids),
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<CustomerDto>>() {}).getBody()
```

Comment: now I have got 500 internal server error but probably it is because of my code right ? i mean now the json request format is correct probably.

Comment: What does the exception say on the server side?

Comment: Are you able to access the ids on the server with the debugger? If you can, your endpoint works as expected, at least on the request side.

Comment: 2018-10-05 17:07:55,020 ERROR [] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]:181 - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/api/v1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.customer.customers.service.customerService.findCustomerByIds(LocGrpService.java:33)